# What is the proper way to assign an array item's value based on a checkbox status?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I was hoping this would work:

```
var title = document.getElementById('cat_title');
var active = document.getElementById('cat_active');

var category = {
    title: title.value,
    active: $(active).prop("checked");
}
```

When the form is submitted, and if the checkbox is checked, it inserts "true" into the active field. When it's not checked, it sends nothing but I'd like it to actually send "false".

Example of saved document if form is submitted WITHOUT checkbox checked:

```
{
    _id: "lklajdlfjkasdf",
    title: "Some Title"
}
```

Example of saved document if form is submitted WITH checkbox checked:

```
{
    _id: ";klajsdfadsf"
    title: "Some Title",
    active: true <-- saved as boolean, good.
}
```

I'd like to keep the logic within the array. I understand another method to handle this... well there are several. I can perform some if/else and push to the array, but I feel I'm missing something simple with this array.

Thank you!

-------- Edit ---------

Details requested:

I'm inserting the record as a document in MongoDB. When the checkbox isn't checked, it inserts nothing into the active key/value pair. To answer various comments throughout, I need this as a boolean value, not a string. I'm trying some of the suggestions now and will update. Thank you all very much.... I've also updated my question above in more detail.

Comment: Could you explain a little better?

Comment: Can't repo, works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7e787tm/

Comment: That's an Object Literal in JavaScript, like an Associative Array sort of. Is that enclosed inside an Event handler? More code please.

Comment: Please provide more information. `$(active).prop("checked")` will return `false`, so the problem is probably rather with the code that processes this information.

Comment: Where are you checking the value of `action`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be what gets inserted into the database then? An empty value is the same as false/null/nil. I think you should be focused on when your retrieving from the database: `What to do when the active field of the table is empty?`

Comment: @kdogisthebest Yes I can check on empty, but I wanted to be more explicit in the data. Although not truly needed, I find it easier to query later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if that code carried the false value up to the database insertion, inserting a false value into the database will only make it a null field, which is the equivalent of setting it to nothing.

So the two options you have are to:

1) Check for a null field when retrieving the rows from the database

OR

2) Use the string value of `"false"` in the database and check for that instead

Comment: This is starting to make more sense. It turns out that when looking at the full document object instead it does indeed say "false" as boolean, but on my application end it interprets it as null and displays nothing, but interprets true as something and displays the word true with my template helper.

Comment: So I have an interface into mongo through the client that shows it as completely empty, but in Mongo shell I can see it says false.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. My lack of clarity on the client side of my app probably caused a bit of confusion in my question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1447679 Anytime!

Comment: *"inserting a false value into the database will only make it a null field"* I assume you are specifically talking about mongoDB here? Otherwise I'd say this statement is presumptuous. It probably depends on the database and the data type of the column/field how the value `false` is actually stored.

Comment: @FelixKling yes when I made that statement it was based off of my prior experience with mongoDB. I didn't mean to make it sound so general but yea it would most definitely depend on your database structure.